XCode 15.3 IOS build error : Incompatible function pointer types for YGMeasureFunc
I'm encountering an error while trying to build my React Native iOS app. The error message I'm receiving is:

Incompatible function pointer types passing 'YGSize (YGNodeConstRef,
float, YGMeasureMode, float, YGMeasureMode)' (aka 'struct YGSize
(const struct YGNode , float, enum YGMeasureMode, float, enum
YGMeasureMode)') to parameter of type 'YGMeasureFunc' (aka 'struct
YGSize ()(struct YGNode *, float, enum YGMeasureMode, float, enum
YGMeasureMode)')


I'm not entirely sure what's causing this error or how to resolve it. From what I understand, it seems to be related to incompatible function pointer types for YGMeasureFunc.
I've tried researching this issue, but I couldn't find a clear solution. Has anyone encountered a similar problem before, and if so, how did you resolve it?

it might be specific to that DateTimePicker library? have you tried uninstalling it and try to rebuild it again?

Thanks! I tried that but it didn't work

Change YGNodeConstRef to YGNodeRef in RNDateTimePickerShadowView.m line 44 (in function RNDateTimePickerShadowViewMeasure) and everything seems back to normal)


in older wesion they did the opposite,
https://github.com/react-native-datetimepicker/datetimepicker/issues/866
with doing your suggestion it worked. But why

same thought crossed my mind.

This works, but how can I manage this change in a team? Should I ask each dev to manually modify RNDateTimePickerShadowView.m? This is the Pods folder.
In addition, if I ever remove my Pods (when I want to do a fresh pod install), I have to remember to apply the change again. Is there an automatic way to keep track of this type of change?

@CezarCobuz I'm using this fix for Podfile
First Update node_modules/@react-native-community/datetimepicker/ios/RNDateTimePickerShadowView.m
Then run
`
npx patch-package @react-native-community/datetimepicker --exclude 'nothing'
`
Add
"postinstall": "patch-package"
To your packages.json

Fixed thank you!

Waseem, for me reverse of this works:
Change YGNodeRef to YGNodeConstRef in RNDateTimePickerShadowView.m line 44 (in function RNDateTimePickerShadowViewMeasure) and everything seems back to normal)
https://i.sstatic.net/lQNZL3a9.png

In my case i have already YGNodeRef then i change with YGNodeConstRef and its work
Screenshot
